# slicer3d and python pyradiomics error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use pyradiomics extension on slicer 3d. I have an issue that I think it's related to my python installation. I tried to reinstall pyradiomics with no results. This is the error I get

```
RadiomicsCLI standard error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Slicer.app/Contents/Extensions-26813/SlicerRadiomics/lib/Slicer-4.8/cli-modules/SlicerRadiomicsCLIScript", line 6, in <module>
    from radiomics.scripts import commandline
  File "/Applications/Slicer.app/Contents/Extensions-26813/SlicerRadiomics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/radiomics/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import collections  # noqa: F401
  File "/Applications/Slicer.app/Contents/lib/Python/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _collections import deque, defaultdict
ImportError: No module named _collections



RadiomicsCLI completed with errors
```

anybody has an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This was a build error and has since been fixed.